# why is onWindowAttached function not be called by firebreath in opera browser

Tags: firebreath

this is my snippet

```
bool hello::onWindowAttached(FB::AttachedEvent *evt, FB::PluginWindow *win)
{
    m_window = win;
    if (m_api)
        m_api->m_win = m_window;

    if (m_api->m_win)
    {
        FB::PluginWindowWin* wnd = reinterpret_cast<FB::PluginWindowWin*>(m_api->m_win);
        HWND hwnd = wnd->getHWND();

        MessageBox(hwnd,L"000",L"000",MB_OK);
    }
    return false;
}
```

my problem is the **onWindowAttached** not be fired ever, so i can not get window handler to draw the region in html page.

Answer (score 0):

i resolve it by create new firebreath project, i guess when i created the previous project i selected to no UI parameter to cause this problem.

Comment: If that's what the problem was you could have edited PluginConfig.cmake and changed it.